# How can a VS / Xamarin project whose connections have been undone be reattached?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android, xamarin, visual-studio-extensions

I've been experimenting with / checking out Xamarin in Visual Studio for the last couple of daze.

Yesterday, though, I opened the Android SDK Manager, and saw there were four (I think it was) packages that needed to be updated. The attempt to do so failed, though, saying “*A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means android sdk manager...*").

I then closed and restarted VS2013 / Xamarin. Subsequent attempts to open the SDK manager just result in an err msg ("Command did not execute successfully due to an unexpected exception. Please check the output window for additional information"). Here are the "More Details":

*System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Mono.VisualStudio.Extension.ProcessWrapper.RunWithOutput(String executable, Int32 waitTime, String workingDir, IVsOutputWindowPane outputPane, String[] arguments)
   at Mono.Android.VisualStudio.MonoAndroidSdk.StartAndroidSdkManager()
   at Mono.Android.VisualStudio.Commands.StartSdkManager.Execute(IMenuCommand command)
   at Mono.VisualStudio.Extension.Commands.VsCommandExtensionAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
   at Mono.VisualStudio.Extension.TracingExtensions.ShieldUI(ITracer tracer, Action action, String format, String[] args)*

Now (even after restarting Windows) I'm not even able to open the project due, I assume, to the interrupted state of the sidetracked upgrade. These are what I see:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There were also these err msgs:

*Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - PlatypusMobile.Android, "C:\Users\clay\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PlatypusMobile\PlatypusMobile.Android.csproj*"

*Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - PlatypusMobile, "C:\Users\clay\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PlatypusMobile\PlatypusMobile.sln"*

Also, one of the err msgs said to look in:

```
C:\users\clay\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

Here are the most interesting parts of that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:03:09.061</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 version: 12.0.30110.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:03:09.061</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in User Groups: Administrators Users</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:03:09.061</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Available Drive Space: C:\ drive has 820592128000 bytes</description>
  </entry>
. . .
  <entry>
    <record>924</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:03:55.266</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
  </entry>
  . . .
  <entry>
    <record>1001</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:04:42.000</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1011</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:09:31.962</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
    <hr>80131509</hr>
    <errorinfo>This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1012</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:09:31.963</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
    <hr>80131509</hr>
    <errorinfo>This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1014</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:17:40.128</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1015</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:17:42.660</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>There is already a logger with the name 'Xamarin.Android'</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>1016</record>
    <time>2014/03/28 15:17:42.660</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MonoAndroidPackage]</description>
    <guid>{296E6A4E-2BD5-44B7-A96D-8EE3D9CDA2F6}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>There is already a logger with the name 'Xamarin.Android'</errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

How can I recombine the shattered shards and get the project to open again so that I can retry upgrading the Android SDK packages? Can Humpty-Dumpty be put back together again?

Note: In the meantime, I have my first app up and running in Android Studio.

Comment: "On Windows this typically means android sdk manager..." looks cut off...?

Comment: Sorry about that; a more full vat of verbiage: "On Windows this typically means that a program Is using that Folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.) Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software. Please also close any running programs that may be accessing the directory [Bla]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me VS restart has solved the incompatibility issues both for iOS and Android projects

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to upgrade the Andrdoid SDK packages from Xamarin Studio? 
You can just go to Tools-> Open Android SDK Manager...

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin Studio; I was using the Xamarin add-in to Visual Studio. Even that is, at least for now, "out," though - I'm using Android Studio to create the Android app. If and when we create an iOS version, we'll revisit it...